# Alexa VideoApp.Launch directive - The target device does not support the specified directive

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to use the VideoApp.Launch directive within my custom skill. Therefore I set the skill information global field for video app to true and added those required intents for video player.

Afterwards I'm started to test it with an [example from this page](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/12826e9e-e06a-4ab4-a583-8e074709a9f3/how-to-build-alexa-skills-for-echo-show1)

Before I added the Video directive alexa was simple returning the output content. But after adding this directory I'm getting the error: **The target device does not support the specified directive**. I couldn't find any documentation which addresses this issue. Is there a device setting which I missed?

Update: I tried it for the Display.RenderTemplate as well with the same outcome. Error: The target device does not support the specified directive. I set the required global fields to true for audio, render template and video.

**What I checked so far is: msg.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces**

```
    "supportedInterfaces": {
      "AudioPlayer": {}
    }
```

I am using the echo. Why are here no other Interfaces available? How can I make them available?

My Code and Error Message are below.

```
    /**
  *
  * main() will be invoked when you Run This Action
  *
  * @param Cloud Functions actions accept a single parameter, which must be a JSON object.
  *
  * @return The output of this action, which must be a JSON object.
  *
  */
var main = function(msg) {
   var response = {
     version: "1.0",
     response: {
       outputSpeech: {
         type: "PlainText",
         text: "" + 'JSON.stringify(msg.request.intent)' //'.slots.questionContent.value'
       },
       "directives": [
        {
         "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
         "videoItem":
         {
             "source": "https://www.example.com/video/sample-video-1.mp4",
            "metadata": {
                 "title": "Title for Sample Video",
                 "subtitle": "Secondary Title for Sample Video"              
            }
         }
        }    
     ],
     "reprompt": null
     }, "sessionAttributes": null

   };
   return {
     statusCode: 200,
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
     body: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(response)).toString("base64")
   };
};
```

## Error Message in Alexa History:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your device "Amazon Echo" does not have a display for the video. The "Amazon Echo Show" supports the following:

```
    "supportedInterfaces": {
      "Display": {},
      "AudioPlayer": {},
      "VideoApp": {}
    }
```

More information here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/best-practices-for-echo-show-skills.html#parse-supported-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Second, you should not have `"sessionAttributes": null` in the request. It is also written in the documentation.

> Note: The shouldEndSession parameter must not be included in the
>   response, even if the value is set to null.

https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/videoapp-interface-reference.html